# Search and replace XML namespace prefix in XHTML+XML files in Eclipse

Tags: java, regex, xml, eclipse

I have a bunch of XHTML+XML based files with `<t:xxx>` tags. I'd like to use regex based search & replace function in Eclipse 4.4.2 for Java EE to replace the XML namespace prefix `t` by `tr`, i.e. replace them all with `<tr:xxx>`, including self-closing ones like `<t:xxx/>`.

Any regex guru out there that want to help a novice?

Comment: Just use 't' for Trinidad's namespace shortname, you won't have to make any other replacement. eg. `xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad"`

Comment: Thats a possibility i thought of, but want to have my code clean. Other legacy projects use the `<t:.*`-tag for tomahawk projects.

Comment: Then you just have to make plain replacements (no regex) of `<t:` with `<tr:` and `</t:` with `</tr:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some try and error, i got the regex done to replace the tags, and only the tags, safely.

**For self-closing tags:**
Search for `<t:(.*?)/>` and replace with `<tr:\1/>`.

**For standard tags**
I did not found a good and safe solution else than the plain replacements Zim suggests. But for the record, i created this `<t:([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b(.*?)>((?s).*?)</t:\1>`. Maybe someone can use it. The problem with it is, i dont know how to correctly match multiple nested tags that are all the same.